# I am working for a project and I have to get data from a WSDL

Tags: php

I am confused on this and I appreciate if someone helps me.I am working for a project and I have to get data from a WSDL.this is my webservice url .
url.http://203.109.97.241/axis/services/searchhoteldetails?wsdl
i am first in xml integration.so i dont know how to get data fronm this url.i try to get country name by this way.

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("http://203.109.97.241/axis/services/searchhoteldetails?wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));

$something =  $client->getHotelDetailsXMLResponse(array("country"=>"india"));

echo "<pre>"; print_r($something);
die();
?>
```

but i cant get result..any one pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are using wrong method name.

Actual method name is  **getHotelDetailsXML**

Request call should look like :

```
$something =  $client->getHotelDetailsXML($xml_request);
```

$xml_request is request xml. (Please get this xml from document and assign to this variable.).

Modified code:

```
<?php

$xml_request = "<HotelSearchRequest> <clientinfo> <companycode>companycode</companycode> <username>username</username> <password>password</password> </clientinfo> <hotelinfo> <country>India</country> <city>Goa</city> <checkindate>20/04/2014</checkindate> <checkoutdate>21/04/2014</checkoutdate> <hotelname>thaj</hotelname> <norooms>2</norooms> <starrating/> <roomtype/> <responsetype>C</responsetype> <roominginfo> </hotelinfo> </HotelSearchRequest>";

$client = new SoapClient("http://203.109.97.241/axis/services/searchhoteldetails?wsdl", array('soap_version'   => SOAP_1_2));

$something =  $client->getHotelDetailsXML($xml_request);

var_dump($something);
die();
?>
```

Comment: thanks nana.i try with your code.put <hotelinfo>tag in this code insted <sample xml request from api document>.in my xml <hotelinfo>tag contain country,city other deatails.but i can get an error message like string '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  <HotelErrorResponse>  <Descripition>Error in Search request</Descripition>  <DetailDescripition>Improper xml structure</DetailDescripition></HotelErrorResponse>' (length=198).what happended..?

Comment: this is my xml document<HotelSearchRequest>
<clientinfo>
<companycode>companycode</companycode>
<username>username</username>
<password>password</password>
</clientinfo>
<hotelinfo>
<country>India</country>
<city>Goa</city>
<checkindate>20/04/2014</checkindate>
<checkoutdate>21/04/2014</checkoutdate>
<hotelname>thaj</hotelname>
<norooms>2</norooms>
<starrating/>
<roomtype/>
<responsetype>C</responsetype>
<roominginfo>
</hotelinfo>
</HotelSearchRequest>

Comment: Now are on right track ...
$xml_request = "<HotelSearchRequest> <clientinfo> <companycode>companycode</companycode> <username>username</username> <password>password</password> </clientinfo> <hotelinfo> <country>India</country> <city>Goa</city> <checkindate>20/04/2014</checkindate> <checkoutdate>21/04/2014</checkoutdate> <hotelname>thaj</hotelname> <norooms>2</norooms> <starrating/> <roomtype/> <responsetype>C</responsetype> <roominginfo> </hotelinfo> </HotelSearchRequest>";

Comment: nana chorge.thank you very much.its now working..greate job brother.i will expect more in future.

Comment: nana bai one more doubt.how to echo only country name in this xml.in the  code you give get all details of hotel.when i need only one field like country or room number how to write the code..i try with this code foreach($something->hotelinfo->country as $item)
{
 echo $item->country;
} but i cant get result.Get an eror Trying to get property of non-object.

Comment: Use some XML to Array libraries for parsing xml.
Refer : http://www.lalit.org/lab/convert-xml-to-array-in-php-xml2array.
You can pass your XML result-set to this and you will get array..and further you can traverse array easily.
Try this and let me know.